Fubini's theorem double integral
I tried to solve the exercise below, but I'm not sure of my answer:
What does the change in order of integration give in the following integrals?
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\left( \int_{0}^{\sin(x)}f(x,y)dy\right) dx$$
My answer is this:
By changing the order of integration I find that $0\leq y\leq 1$ and $\arcsin(y)\leq x\leq \pi$.
Can someone help me please.
Thank you in advance for your help.

It might help to draw the area you are integrating over

By drawing the area you are integrating over, you see that you integrate "over the area under a sine curve" between $x=0$ and $x=\pi$. Changing the order of integration leads to the following integral:
$$\int_0^\pi\left(\int_0^{\sin(x)}f(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}y\right)\;\mathrm{d}x
=\int_0^1\left(\int_{\arcsin(y)}^{\pi-\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}x\right)\;\mathrm{d}y.$$
I drew the integration areas in desmos:


Thank you for your reply or response, but why $\pi-\arcsin(y)$?

because for a fixed $y$ the $x$-values inside the region are just in between those two values (it corresponds with a horizontal line in the picture)

You are basically looking for the $x$-values such that for a fixed $y$, $y\in[0,\sin x]$, and the $x$-values that fit this description are exactly the given ones

But it's the most intuïtive/easy to understand when you just draw the region and let $x$ depend on $y$

btw, $\pi-arcsin(y)$ is the other value in $[0,\pi]$ with sine value $y$.
